# Using dual criteria with wmic and trying to create a batch file var

Tags: batch-file, variables, scripting, pid, wmic

So I am trying to create a variable from the output of the below command in a batch file. It works fine at the command prompt where I get the process ID 1292:

> C:\Documents and Settings\user>wmic process where (name="cmd.exe" and CommandLine like "%%%queue%%%") get ProcessID

Which Returns

```
ProcessId
1292
```

if I do this I get the return I need if only one instance is running:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('wmic process get processid /value ^| find "="') do set "%%f"
echo processid is %processid%
```

However, I would like to use the multiple content combo because if I want to get the processID for an exe that is running multiple times, at least I can narrow it down.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "queue=testing"

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
        wmic process 
        where "name='cmd.exe' And commandLine like '%%%queue%%%'" 
        get ProcessID /value
    ') do echo %%a
```

or

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "queue=testing"

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
        wmic process 
        where ^(
            name^="cmd.exe" 
            and commandLine like "%%%queue%%%" 
        ^)
        get ProcessID /value
    ') do echo %%a
```

just two different samples of escaping the `wmic` command inside the `for /f`.

- In the first case the `where` conditions are wrapped in double quotes with values using single quotes. There is not need for escape characters as the double quotes will deal with it, but all the conditions must be on the same line.
- In the second case the `where` conditions are wrapped with parenthesis with values enclosed in double quotes. Some of the characters will need escape characters, but you have more options on how to write the command.

Note that these samples have a problem that probably will not affect you: both samples search for `cmd` instances, and the `wmic` command is started inside a separate `cmd` instance (the way `for /f` executes commands), and that instance will also match the condition (it includes the same substring in its own command line).

**edited** to adapt to comments

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "queue=testing"

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
        wmic process 
        where ^(
            name^="cmd.exe" 
            and commandLine like "%%%queue%%%" 
            and not commandLine like "%%[{%random%%random%%random%}]%%"
        ^)
        get ProcessID /value 2^>nul 
    ') do echo %%a
```

To avoid the inclusion of the `cmd` instance created by the `for /f` command that holds the `wmic` command we only need to include an additional condition that will math this problematic instance (the condition will be in the command line of the `cmd` instance) but that must not match the instance we are looking for.

Comment: your code works perfectly. I had the same but forgot the /value. makes a difference. However, you are correct that the wmic command started a separate cmd that clears. But before it clears it returns a PID that displays vs. the PID i'm looking for. Anyway to get around this? I was thinking that I could write to file and remove the errant PID and echo the file.

Comment: @DjeliStyles, answer updated. See if this works for you

Comment: so is the random value three different values {%valueA%%valueB%%valueC%%} or the same value three times? Like %dirPath%%dirPath%%dirPath%

Comment: @DjeliStyles, 3 random values, but it is the same if they are three times the same value. It is just an example, not a requirement. The requirement is that the command line of the `for /f` background application includes something (anything) that will not be in any valid/searched `cmd` instance. That way the `and not ...` in the `where`  clause will discard it.

Comment: Thank You VERY MUCH!! Works like a charm. I have to ask, what is the purpose of this:  set "queue=testing" and what is the relation to this: and commandLine like "%%%queue%%%"

Comment: @DjeliStyles, just an assumption, in your original code you used `%%%queue%%%`, a escaped percent sign for the `like` operator and a variable. I just keeped it.